# Заставляем Outlook отправить письмо при помощи PowerShell

Tags: powershell, outlook

Работает вот такой скрипт:

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = "yma@perm.ru"
$Mail.Subject = "123"
$Mail.Body ='123'
$Mail.Send()
```

Но если я делаю командлет
`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Send-Email\Send-Email.psm1`
с кодом:

```
Function Global:Send-Email { 
[cmdletbinding()]
Param (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=0)]
[String]$Address = "yma@perm.ru",
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=1)]
[String]$Subject = "123",
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=2)]
[String]$Body = "123"
      )
Begin {
    }
Process {
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = "$Address"
$Mail.Subject = $Subject
$Mail.Body =$Body
$Mail.Send()
       } 
End {
   } 
}
```

И запускаю его:

```
Import-Module Send-Email
Send-Email
```

То мой Outlook 2010 выдает сообщение:

[image: Outlook Err]

Как избавиться от этого сообщения?

Comment: А чем не устраивает `Send-MailMessage` - в чём необходимость отправлять именно через Outlook?

Answer (score 2):

Посмотри свой скрипт, и убери строку:

```
$Outlook.Quit()
```

Также брал пример этого скрипта в интернете и столкнулся с этой "проблемой".